# How do I solve the polynomial exercise?

Tags: polynomials

Let $f\in\ \mathbb{R}[x]$ be a polynomial with the property that $f(x^2+3x+1)=f^2(x)+3f(x)+1$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $f=x$.
I tried for $x=-1 => f(-1)=-1$ and for $x=1=>f(1)=1$, but I do not have any idea how to prove for the general case. I think about induction but I'm not really sure about it. Can you help me out?

If you can please try to tell me a way without using sequences.

Comment: Your request makes no sense. To formulate this problem you need to talk about the natural numbers and functions on them. That is what sequences are. If you can't use sequences, then you can't write your question.

Comment: @Kronnected Sorry but I was just saying that "If you can". I see your point, but I want to know if there are any other ways to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You got $f(1)=1$ by putting $x=0$ in the equation.

Putting $x=1$ you get $f(4)=4$.
Putting $x=4$ you get $f(29)=29$

Define $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+3x_n+1$ and $x_1=1$. Then $x_n$ is strictly increasing and $f(x_n)=x_n$.

If $f$ has degree $m$, then $f(x)-x=0$ at the $m+1$ distinct points $x_1,x_2,...,x_{m+1}$.

Therefore, $f(x)-x=0$.

Comment: Can I solve the exercise without series?

Comment: @OvyOvy What series are you seeing?

Comment: You defined $x_{n+1}$. Is it not a series?

Comment: @OvyOvy That is not what is called a [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)) The function $x_n$ is a sequence, used here only to define some values at which we would like to evaluate the equation.

Comment: Sorry but I am not used writing math in English. How are they called then?

Answer (score 0):

For all such $x_0$,for which $f(x_0)=x_0$, we notice that $f(x_0^2 +3x_0+1)= x_0^2+3x_0+1$.

So, inductively we can generate infinitely many inputs for which $f(x)=x$, even if we know one such input and we already have one,  $f(0)=0$.

But, $f(x) - x$ is a polynomial, so it must have finite no. of roots. 
So, only possibility is $f(x) - x= 0$